# Automatically changing URL references from an internal source to an external one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, lamp, cdn

I would like to set all image references (really just references to a specific folder),

e.g. `mywedomain.com/images/myimage.jpg`, where `mywebdomain.com/images/myimage.jpg` would actually point to `mycdn.com/images/myimage.jpg`.

But keep the internal reference in the code/markup itself.  I am wondering how one would handle this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if it is on the same server or not as to how exactly you should handle that.

If it is on the same server, and within the document root, it would be easiest with a rewrite, using `mod_rewrite`.

Inside your main directory `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/images/(.+)$ /mycdn.com/images/$1 [L]
```

If it is not in the document root, or on another server, then a redirect might be easier.

```
RedirectMatch ^/images/(.+)$ http://mycdn.com/images/$1
```

Though this will be noticeable on the client, if they were looking at the request log.  If you want it to be transparent, then you could proxy the request on your server.

Create a PHP file (or other language you use, you mention LAMP, hence PHP).

```
<?php

$reqImage = $_GET['image'];
$mimeTypes = array('gif' => 'gif', 'jpg' => 'jpeg', 'jpeg' => 'jpeg',
                   'png' => 'png');

$matches = array();
if (preg_match("/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.(gif|jpg|png)$/", $reqImage, $matches)) {
   header('Content-Type: image/' . $mimeTypes[$matches[1]]);
   @readfile("http://mycdn.com/images/" . $reqImage);
} else {
   header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
}

exit;
```

Note the need to pass out the [Internet media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types) when providing the image, as Apache will be expecting something different from a PHP file, and normally handles that for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Orbling. I am going to try both the mod_rewrite and the php one.  Both are useful and I would like to get comfortable with them.

Comment: @Sean Powell: Aye, always worth getting to grips with both concepts.